# Swiftui sheets on mac app doesn't work properly

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

When attempting to use sheets on a Mac OS app, it's not interactable (sliding down to go back to the previous view) like on iOs. Is this normal or would I need a workaround to go back to the previous view?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It is normal. On macOS sheet does not have such "interactive close" feature - you have to close it explicitly, by button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ll need a close button on macOS, there is no dismissal gesture. If your app supports iOS too, it’s probably wise to have a close button there too — not all iPad users are familiar with the gesture, and the gesture doesn’t work on landscape phones.